# R pheathmap, how to set the same scale in two heatmap images?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, pheatmap

I've two matrices in two different csv files, and I want to plot them having the same color scale.

This is what I have now and it's NOT working:

[image]

As you can see, both the images use the same color ranges (from blue to red), but their meanings are different: they have different intervals.

I want to associate the same colors to the same value range in the two heatmaps.

Here's my code for an heatmap:

```
library(pheatmap)
datatable_normal = data.matrix(read.table(fileName, sep="\t", header=T, row.names=1))
pheatmap(datatable_normal, cluster_rows=FALSE, cluster_cols=FALSE, show_rownames=T, width=10, height=10)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Couldn't you merge the two csv files and then run two different plots by subsetting the observations based on which file it came from?

Comment: Maybe... how can I do it?

Comment: I just read the package's vignette. I'm surprised it doesn't have a `subset` argument.

What happens if you add a column in both csv files indicating whether it belongs to `csv1` or `csv2` (let's call the variable `csv_filter`) and then do the following:

`library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(csv1, csv2)

datatable_normal1 = data.matrix(read.table(fileName[which(fileName$csv_filter == 1),], sep="\t", header=T, row.names=1))

pheatmap(datatable_normal1, cluster_rows=FALSE, cluster_cols=FALSE, show_rownames=T, width=10, height=10)`

Answer (score 3):

You can set the same scale by giving the same `breaks`.

Here is my example:

```
library(pheatmap)

  ## example data   
set.seed(1); test1 <- matrix(rnorm(25, 0, 10), 5, 5)
set.seed(2); test2 <- matrix(rnorm(25, 30, 10), 5, 5)
colnames(test1) = paste0("Test", 1:5); rownames(test1) = paste0("Gene", 1:5)
colnames(test2) = paste0("Test", 1:5); rownames(test2) = paste0("Gene", 1:5)

  ## make breaks from combined range
Breaks <- seq(min(c(test1, test2)), max(c(test1, test2)), length = 100)

  ## draw   
pheatmap(test1, breaks = Breaks, cluster_rows=FALSE, cluster_cols=FALSE)
pheatmap(test2, breaks = Breaks, cluster_rows=FALSE, cluster_cols=FALSE)
```

[image][image]